# Why does this parallel algorithm run more slowly than its sequential counterpart?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

Sequential:

```
void do(List<D> d, final List<C> c) {
for (D datum : d)
    getChampoid(datum, c).tally(datum);
```

Parallel:

```
static final int procs = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(procs);
void do(List<D> d, final List<C> c) {
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final D datum : d)
        futures.add(pool.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getChampoid(datum, c).tally(datum);
            }

        }));
    for (Future f : futures)
        try {
            f.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm stumped because to me they look like they do the exact same thing, the parallel version should just be faster, but it's an order of magnitude slower. Any thoughts?

FYI both d and c are huge lists with somewhere between thousands and hundreds of thousands of items.

Comment: How exactly do you know that it runs slower?

Comment: In the first code snippet, you're passing the list `d` to `tally()` while in the second you're passing the list item `datum`.  Is that a typo in one version or the other?

Comment: It's impossible to say why because you don't provide enough information.

Comment: How many items does `List<D> d` contain? How long sequential and parallel versions execute?

Answer (score 4):

> the parallel version should just be faster,

That is a common misconception.

> but it's an order of magnitude slower.

A common result

> Any thoughts?

Using multiple threads has overhead which one thread doesn't have.  The overhead can be orders of magnitude higher than the work actually done, making it much slower.  If the work done is much larger than the overhead you can get very good scalability.

e.g. say it costs about 10 micro-seconds to pass a task to another thread.  If your task takes 1 micro-second, the overhead can kill your performance.  However, if the task takes 100 micro-seconds, you could see a significant performance improvement and worth paying the price of the overhead.

In short, nothing is free esp not multiple thread.

Comment: Yes I understand this much. However in this case it really should be faster. When I do it in python it speeds it up quite a lot.

Comment: How much faster was python than Java?  If your tasks are slow, using more threads helps.  What you can do is to create one task per processor which does a portion of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

A) have you ruled out any synchronization? If `getChampoid` hits on a synchronized data structure (such as a Hashtable), i'm not surprised performance drops drastically.

B) with Java, **Object overhead** is usually what kills performance. Make sure to use profilers such as VisualVM. In your case, I would not be surprised if you see a lot of time going into **garbage collection**.

Consider breaking your list `d` into a small number of parts, then processing each part in a thread. Right now, for every `datum` you will create a `Runnable` *and* a `Future` object, and probably some more. Which, when `d` is large, means a lot of work for the garbage collector (and here, it cannot be optimized away by Hotspot either).

Comment: A) getChampoid() reads (but does not write) to the list c. However, the tally() method is synchronized and requires writing to a shared array list.

Comment: @EarlBellinger Writing to a shared resource will be slower from multiple threads than just one. Can you return the result which needs to be merged instead i.e. with a Callable.

Comment: There you go, you've got your synchronization. Only one can write at a time, and others will wait doing nothing. Sometimes you can work around this, e.g. by using `AtomicIntegerArray`. But can you A) chunk your data as suggested in this post and B) give each thread a separate storage, and merge the storages efficiently afterwards?